# C++ Creating a function that is being pointed to as an argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers

So this is confusing to explain, but I will try my best.

I have a function one of my classes that takes a function pointer as an argument, and what I would like to do is define the function as part of the argument. ie:

```
object->setFunctionPointer({string a = ""; return a;});
```

Is this possible? if so, what is the proper syntax of this?

Comment: How is `setFunctionPointer` defined?

Comment: std::function? Use of Lamba?

Comment: If this function accepts `std::function<std::string()>` then you could use `object->setFunctionPointer([] () { return std::string(""); });`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can do it. You can use C++ lambda (anonymous functions).

See the sample code at http://ideone.com/8ZTWSU

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef const char * (*funcptr)();
funcptr s;
void setFuncPtr(funcptr t)
{
    s = t;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    setFuncPtr([]{return "Hello \n"; });
    printf("%s\n", s());
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: -1 you don't need C++11 for function pointers, and lambda expressions are not compatible with function pointers.

Comment: @concept3d he's mentionning inline function declaration, not function pointers. And stateless closures *are* convertible to a function pointer (to their **operator()**).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. So, what is the alternative? Or is there any way to convert lambda to function pointer safely?

Comment: That's it - lambdas implicitly convert to a function pointer in suitable contexts. If it doesn't, prefix it with *.

Comment: @Quentin: Can you give me some reference or links to read more about this (closure, lambdas in C++).

Comment: @dbasic I can't really do better than google for articles, but [there](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) you [go](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Answer (score 0):

If your function is a member of a class, you cannot take an ordinary function pointer to store its address. What you need is a delegate; which are specialised function pointers for methods.  Search the internet for C++ delegate and you should find numerous examples.

(Note: maybe there is an exception for static methods; I don't remember.)

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about C++ you should use std::function and not function pointers. Unless you are interfacing with C APIs.

```
class Foo{

SetFunc(std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    m_func = func;
} 

private:
std::function<void(int)> m_func;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example. Since c++11 this is the way to go:

```
#include<functional> 
#include<string> 
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
class Object
{
    public: 
        void setFunctionPointer(function<string(void)> function)
        {
            m_function = function;
        }
        string run()
        {
            return m_function();    
        }
    private:
        function<string(void)> m_function;
};

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    Object *object = new Object;
    object->setFunctionPointer([]{string a = "FOO"; return a;}); // here is the function assignment 
    cout << object->run() << endl;
    delete object;
}
```

When run this prints `FOO` to stdout.